# R, how to use for loop to make each element in the list executed by the same command

Tags: r

R,  how to use for loop to make each element in the list executed by the same command

for example, datanewV_102,datanewV_103,datanewV_105 are all data frame with 100 observation and 50 columns.

I want to drop the same column, the best 6th column, for all three data frame

The desired result:  ( no new data frame, edit on the existing data frame.)

datanewV_102,datanewV_103,datanewV_105 becomes data frames with 100 observation and 49 columns.

My code was like:

vlist12 = list(datanewV_102,datanewV_103,datanewV_105)
for (v12 in vlist12) {
v12 = v12[-6]
}

However, in my result datanewV_102,datanewV_103,datanewV_105 remain the same. The v12 is the copy of datanewV_105 and with the 6th column dropped.

How can I revise that? if must use for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your output to also be a list, to be able to store all these separate dataframes (in your current version, `v12` gets overwritten at each occurrence of the loop).

It is possible with a `for` loop, if you loop on the index. For example:

```
datanewV_102 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:10],
                           y = LETTERS[1:10])
datanewV_103 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:10],
                           y = LETTERS[1:10])
datanewV_105 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:10],
                           y = LETTERS[1:10])



datanew_list <- list(datanewV_102,datanewV_103,datanewV_105)

output_list1 <- list()

for(i in seq_along(datanew_list)){
  cur_df <- datanew_list[[i]]
  output_list1[[i]] <- cur_df[-2]
}
```

But here is typically a case where `lapply` makes things easier to read. For example:

```
remove_col <- function(df){
  df[-2]
}

output_list2 <- lapply(datanew_list, remove_col)
```

The two solutions are equivalent:

```
all.equal(output_list1, output_list2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: It gives the output_list2 as a list of desired data rame.  But those desired data frames are not stored as datanewV_102, datanewV_103, datanewV_104. How should I reassign it back?

Comment: Are you sure you should? In every case I can think of, a list is more practical (or even better, a single data frame with an additional column indicating the origin). If you really want to have separate variables, you can always assign them manually as `out1 <- out_list[[1]]` etc. One way to "cheat" and obtain the same result is using `attach()` (after having given appropriate names to the list elements).